# Forcing the use of null value

Tags: typescript

I want to have a variable that can be a number or null. The point of this is to reset the variable some times (by setting it null). The problem is that if I declare the variable with type `number | null`, I can't use it like a number where I know it is a number.

Here's the code:

```
class Test {
    start: number | null = null;

    handler(e: Event) {
        if (this.start === null) {
            this.start = Date.now();
        }

        let time = Date.now() - this.start;
        if (time < 1000) {
            this.start = null;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

The compiler says that `this.start` "is possibly null". How can I can tell it that it's right? Otherwise, is my pattern the problem? Should I use instead a boolean property `hasStarted` so `start` is always a number (or undefined btw)?

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? On 3.3.3, I don't see that error. In fact, even on 2.4.1, I don't see that error. In any case, you can always assert that the value is not null, e.g. `Date.now() - this.start!`

Comment: Consider editing your code to constitute a [mcve] so others can help you.  As it stands, [the code in your question](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoaXrLAJyQC5oA7AVwFsAjePaAH1LJBGgF4mWBudTbACzAkAJiFoAKeMQCiAN3gkkASjR9s2AJYAzaOKT8NEAHS4C7Nh3IsVGdXez7DJpPhQcAImCTwjJAPYA7uJKPPZYAL68YdBiKEgaFPDs0J7evoHB0AC00I7GpkihYdq68YnQADzQAIwADPU2atG5BvkuZpbMIEX2kdEA9P3QRiNNkeFAA) does not show any such error.

Answer (score -1):

Change `start: number | null` to `start?: number` to let the compiler know you are aware that it may sometimes be null and that you will handle it.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. The type declaration is fine; OP wants to know how to avoid the "*is possibly null*" warnings. Also `start?: number` actually means `start: number | undefined`, not `start: number | null`, which is an important distinction. (Not my downvote, BTW)

Comment: Yes, and this is how you avoid the warnings. Either this or by suppressing them. But if you're surpressing warnings, why are you even using TS to begin with? If you want Typescript without the benefits of typescript, that already exists and its called Javascript.

Comment: The warning OP's talking about would be on the line `Date.now() - this.start` (you'd have to remove the `if (this.start === null)` above it though to reproduce the warning because OP's code sample is likely incomplete). This answer does not address that warning at all, and would actually introduce a new warning on the line `this.start = null` because of what I mentioned in my previous comment.